# Convert numbers in a string array (#3, #1, #2, #4) to range (#1:#4)

Tags: c#, algorithm, strings

#### Updated question: [Compress numbers in a string array (#3, #1, #2, #4) to range (#1:#4)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110103/compress-numbers-in-a-string-array-3-1-2-4-to-range-14)

---

This function takes a string array,

```
{"foo", "#123", "#124", "bar", "#125", "#126"}
```

makes a new array with the numbers converted to a range:

```
{"foo", "#123:126", "bar"}
```

and returns:

```
"foo,#123:126,bar"
```

Note it doesn't and shouldn't change `{"#1", "#2"}` to `{"#1:#2"}`

---

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ids = new string[] { "foo", "#12", "#14", "#17", "#13", "#18", "#bar", "#19", "#20", "#25", "#26", "#38", "#39", "baz", "#12", "#13", "#14" };
    Console.WriteLine("foo,#12:#14,#17:#20,#bar,#25,#26,#38,#39,baz,#12:#14");
    Console.WriteLine(Convert(ids));
    Console.Read();
}
static string Convert(IEnumerable<string> arr)
{
    var IDs = arr.ToList();
    var result = new List<string>();
    for (var index = 0; index < IDs.Count; index++)
    {
        var i = IDs[index];
        if (i.StartsWith("#"))
        {
            int fromInt;
            if (int.TryParse(i.Substring(1), out fromInt))
            {
                var plus1 = $"#{fromInt + 1}";
                var plus2 = $"#{fromInt + 2}";
                if (IDs.Contains(plus1) && IDs.Contains(plus2))
                {
                    IDs.Remove(plus1);
                    IDs.Remove(plus2);
                    var toInt = fromInt + 2;
                    while (IDs.Contains($"#{toInt + 1}"))
                    {
                        toInt += 1;
                        IDs.Remove($"#{toInt}");
                    }
                    i = $"#{fromInt}:#{toInt}";
                }
            }
        }
        result.Add(i);
    }
    return string.Join(",", result);
}
```

Comment: What is this method actually doing? I don't get with the ids and ranges. Could you explain it in few words?

Comment: @t3chb0t Please try to infer from the output. It just replaces `#1, #2, #3` to `#1:#3`. And `#60, #50, #70` to `#50-#70`

Comment: Then you must have a typo somewhere. According to what you just said the  `ids` array should be converted into `"foo,#12:#18,#bar,#19:#39,baz,#12:#14"` but your console outputs `"foo,#12:#14,#17:#20,#bar,#25,#26,#38,#39,baz,#12:#14"` :-|

Comment: @t3chb0t No, the array doesn't have #15 or #16. The first console output is the intended output, the second is output by the program's function

Comment: You cannot edit your question after answers are provided and change your code in a way you just did. It makes @GentianKasa review completely invalid.

Comment: You changed the loop from `for` into a `foreach` this is a huge change and made a few other changes that make the review invalid.

Answer (score 2):

In order to improve readability I'd say to not go too deep with the indentation. For example:

```
            if (IDs.Contains(plus1) && IDs.Contains(plus2))
            {
                IDs.Remove(plus1);
                IDs.Remove(plus2);
                var toInt = fromInt + 2;
                while (IDs.Contains($"#{toInt + 1}"))
                {
                    toInt += 1;
                    IDs.Remove($"#{toInt}");
                }
                i = $"#{fromInt}:#{toInt}";
            }
```

can be transformed in:

```
if (!(IDs.Contains(plus1) && IDs.Contains(plus2)))
{
    continue;
}
IDs.Remove(plus1);
IDs.Remove(plus2);
var toInt = fromInt + 2;
while (IDs.Contains($"#{toInt + 1}"))
{
    toInt += 1;
    IDs.Remove($"#{toInt}");
}
i = $"#{fromInt}:#{toInt}";
```

The same can be done with the conditions `if (int.TryParse(i.Substring(1), out fromInt))` and `if (i.StartsWith("#"))` in the upper levels.

The name of the string `i` is a little misleading. `i` is usually used as an index. I think `id` would be a proper name.

The resulting code could be transformed from:

```
var newIDs = new List<string>();
for (var index = 0; index < IDs.Count; index++)
{
    var i = IDs[index];
    if (i.StartsWith("#"))
    {
        int fromInt;
        if (int.TryParse(i.Substring(1), out fromInt))
        {
            var plus1 = $"#{fromInt + 1}";
            var plus2 = $"#{fromInt + 2}";
            if (IDs.Contains(plus1) && IDs.Contains(plus2))
            {
                IDs.Remove(plus1);
                IDs.Remove(plus2);
                var toInt = fromInt + 2;
                while (IDs.Contains($"#{toInt + 1}"))
                {
                    toInt += 1;
                    IDs.Remove($"#{toInt}");
                }
                i = $"#{fromInt}:#{toInt}";
            }
        }
    }
    newIDs.Add(i);
}
return string.Join(",", newIDs);
```

into the following:

```
var newIDs = new List<string>();
for (var index = 0; index < IDs.Count; index++)
{
    var id = IDs[index];
    if (!id.StartsWith("#"))
    {
        newIDs.Add(i);
        continue;
    }
    int fromInt;
    if (!int.TryParse(i.Substring(1), out fromInt))
    {
        newIDs.Add(id);
        continue;
    }
    var plus1 = $"#{fromInt + 1}";
    var plus2 = $"#{fromInt + 2}";
    if (!(IDs.Contains(plus1) && IDs.Contains(plus2)))
    {
        newIDs.Add(id);
        continue;
    }
    IDs.Remove(plus1);
    IDs.Remove(plus2);
    var toInt = fromInt + 2;
    while (IDs.Contains($"#{toInt + 1}"))
    {
        toInt += 1;
        IDs.Remove($"#{toInt}");
    }
    i = $"#{fromInt}:#{toInt}";
    newIDs.Add(id);
}
return string.Join(",", newIDs);
```

Comment: I use foreach to remove items while looping but I just discovered a bug with that and I'm changing it.

Comment: @Elmo edited the answer (and changed the code because there was a bug in my previous version).