# Compress numbers in a string array (#3, #1, #2, #4) to range (#1:#4)

Tags: c#, algorithm, strings, .net

This function takes a string array,

```
{"foo", "#123", "#124", "bar", "#125", "#126"}
```

makes a new array with the numbers converted to a range:

```
{"foo", "#123:126", "bar"}
```

and returns:

```
"foo,#123:126,bar"
```

Note it doesn't and shouldn't change `{"#1", "#2"}` to `{"#1:#2"}`

---

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ids = new string[] {
            "foo", //output: unmodified
            "#60", "#59", "#61", "#62", //from integer is in between, output: #59:#62
            "#12", "#14", "#17", "#13", "#18", "#bar", "#19", "#20", //two ranges and string intertwined, output: #12:#14,#17:#20,#bar
            "#25", "#26", //output: unmodified
            "#39", "#38", //output: unmodified
            "baz", //output: unmodified
            "#12", "#13", "#14" //duplicate sequences, output: #12:#14
        };
        Console.WriteLine("foo,#59:#62,#12:#14,#17:#20,#bar,#25,#26,#38,#39,baz,#12:#14");
        Console.WriteLine(Compress(ids));
        Console.Read();
    }
    static string Compress(IEnumerable<string> IDs)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        var ignore = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var item in IDs)
        {
            if (ignore.Contains(item)) continue;
            var id = item;
            if (id.StartsWith("#"))
            {
                int fromInt;
                if (int.TryParse(id.Substring(1), out fromInt))
                {
                    var less1 = $"#{fromInt - 1}";
                    var plus1 = $"#{fromInt + 1}";
                    var hasPlus1 = IDs.Contains(plus1);
                    if (IDs.Contains(less1) && hasPlus1) continue;
                    var plus2 = $"#{fromInt + 2}";
                    if (hasPlus1 && IDs.Contains(plus2))
                    {
                        ignore.Add(plus1);
                        ignore.Add(plus2);
                        var toInt = fromInt + 2;
                        while (IDs.Contains($"#{toInt + 1}"))
                        {
                            toInt += 1;
                            ignore.Add($"#{toInt}");
                        }
                        id = $"#{fromInt}:#{toInt}";
                    }
                }
            }
            result.Add(id);
        }
        return string.Join(",", result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [my answer on your other (related) post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110092/convert-numbers-in-a-string-array-3-1-2-4-to-range-14/110099#110099) which is still valid here (with the proper modifications obviously) I'd suggest to use brackets even in case of `if` blocks with only 1 instructions. For example:

```
if (IDs.Contains(less1) && hasPlus1) continue;
```

should become something like:

```
if (IDs.Contains(less1) && hasPlus1)
{ 
    continue;
}
```

Also, `var id = item;` can be safely removed and you can work directly on `item`.

By applying all changes the method becomes something like the following:

```
static string Compress(IEnumerable<string> IDs)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    var ignore = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (var item in IDs)
    {
        if (ignore.Contains(item))
        { 
            continue;
        }
        if (!item.StartsWith("#"))
        {
            result.Add(item);
            continue;
        }
        int fromInt;
        if (!(int.TryParse(item.Substring(1), out fromInt)))
        {
            result.Add(item);
            continue;
        }
        var less1 = $"#{fromInt - 1}";
        var plus1 = $"#{fromInt + 1}";
        var hasPlus1 = IDs.Contains(plus1);
        if (IDs.Contains(less1) && hasPlus1)
        { 
            continue;
        }
        var plus2 = $"#{fromInt + 2}";
        if (!(hasPlus1 && IDs.Contains(plus2)))
        {
            result.Add(item);
            continue;
        }
        ignore.Add(plus1);
        ignore.Add(plus2);
        var toInt = fromInt + 2;
        while (IDs.Contains($"#{toInt + 1}"))
        {
            toInt += 1;
            ignore.Add($"#{toInt}");
        }
        result.Add($"#{fromInt}:#{toInt}");
    }
    return string.Join(",", result);
}
```

Comment: @Elmo I added an example of how the code should become IMO. Let me know if anything's unclear.

Comment: First me now you downvoted without giving any reason :-(

Comment: @t3chb0t care to explain what you mean?

Comment: @GentianKasa I understand now, but those are two things (using braces and reducing indent) I didn't want to do because they increase the vertical length.

Comment: @Elmo, I got it :)

Comment: @t3chb0t Yeah I too don't understand what you mean.